# Is there a more common and not humorous word for pedipulate?

Tags: single-word-requests

I just asked a question on The Great Outdoors SE about snowshoes, and said that I found large snowshoes hard to manipulate, and then changed manipulate to pedipulate, not even knowing if that was a word.  But it is! [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pedipulate) says of pedipulate:

> rare
>
> [with object] To work with the feet. Chiefly humorous

And then says of its origin:

> Late 19th century; earliest use found in Family Herald. Humorously
>   from pedi- + -pulate, after manipulate.

I looked up *pedipulate, synonyms* and, on the first two pages of the Google response, found no synonyms. The closest I got was on [Foboko](https://www.foboko.com/sentence-dictionary/english/pedipulate), which said:

> Synonyms for pedipulate
>
> No synonyms were found for this word

But this source did not have a definition or a sample sentence either, so they know less than I do.  And on page two, the search degenerated into ["how to use uttermost in a sentence"](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/uttermost.html), which is unhelpful to the uttermost.

One could, of course, use phrases like "less clumsy", but is there an unhumorous synonym for pedipulate?  I could even use manipulate and people would know what I meant, but is manipulate the only non-humorous answer to my Q?

**Sample sentence:**  I find it difficult to ____________ large snowshoes.

**Response to Comment of @1006a:**  A generic term is too easy.  I'd like something that references feet or brings feet immediately to mind.

Comment: You need to add a sample sentence where you would use pedipulate,

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting *manoeuver*, but that has the same problem. How about *pedoeuver*? :-)

Comment: @user240918 The sample use is embedded in the first sentence of the Q, but I will make it explicit since that seems to be necessary.

Comment: @Peter Schor --  pedoeuver, as used by the Rev. Asa Mahan (1799 to 1889) in [A System of Intellectual Philosophy](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/moa/ACQ7189.0001.001?rgn=main;view=fulltext), and referring to bees.   "the bees had recourse again to the same manoeuver (or rather pedoeuver),....". 1854

Comment: Do you want a word that specifically references the feet, or just something that doesn't reference the hands? If a generic term would work, I think you could use *operate* or *steer* or similar. FWIW, one of the OED's attestations for *pedipulate* is actually in reference to show shoes, so you have precedent ;-).

Comment: Can you say why this is interesting? Ped- as opposed to manipulate might be interesting in some circumstances and can you cite any such circumstances?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin  It is interesting to me (although perhaps not to most people) because I automatically wrote "hard to manipulate large snowshoes" and then had a vision of walking on my hands, with my hands strapped to snowshoes.  Possibly this is interesting only to those with a weird sense of humor.

Answer (score 1):

The esteemed Oxford English Dictionary can only [supply](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/205344#eid17728653) definition No. 7 of **tread**

> **7.** *transitive.* To press (something) downwards with the foot or feet treadling or pedalling.
>
> *The nearer the fore-end of the Treddle you **tread**, the easier you bring down the Pole.*

I don't know how much help this is, but I think it's your best bet.

[image]